# Redux won't update React component when state change

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get my simple Redux React test work. I'm really new to both Redux and React. I've been reading through Redux documentation and in [Troubleshooting](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html) section, it said that reducer should return new object everytime. In my case, I think I'm returning new object...

Any suggestions are appreciate!

My reducer:

```js
const memberOpReducer = (state = {isLoading: true, isLoggedIn: false}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'CHECK_LOGIN_STATUS':
      return {
        isLoading: true
      }
    case 'LOGIN_STATUS':
      return {
        isLoading: false,
        isLoggedIn: action.response.status === 'connected',
        response: action.response
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My actions:

```js
const checkLoginStatus = () => ({
  type: 'CHECK_LOGIN_STATUS'
});

const loginStatus = response => ({
  type: 'LOGIN_STATUS',
  response: response
});

const getLoginStatus = (options = {}) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(checkLoginStatus());
  FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    dispatch(loginStatus(response));
  }, options);
}
```

Please have a look at this working pen: https://codepen.io/mrducnguyen/pen/rGxpGR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `mapStateToProps` function:

```
// Your function, just for reference
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn === undefined ? false : state.isLoggedIn,
    isLoading: state.isLoading === undefined ? true : state.isLoading,
    response: state.response
  }
}
```

You're accessing `state.isLoggedIn`, but you should be accessing `state.memberOpReducer.isLoggedIn`, because you used `combineReducers` which namespaces all of the fields of that reducer under the reducer's name. Same for all the other fields, of course.

```
// Fixed version
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.memberOpReducer.isLoggedIn,
    isLoading: state.memberOpReducer.isLoading,
    response: state.memberOpReducer.response
  }
}
```

Comment: Stupid me... Thank you very much for you help :)